# delete[] operator in C++ not working as it should

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

Please have a look at this below code::

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
         int *ptr;
    
        ptr = new int[100000];
    
        cout<<"\n\n address = "<<ptr;

        for(long int i=0;i<100000;i++)
            *(ptr+i) = i+1;
    
        delete []ptr;
        cout<<"\n\n address = "<<ptr;

        ptr = new int[5];
        cout<<"\n\n address = "<<ptr;
        
        return 0;
    }
```

OUTPUT is:

```
address = 0xd42490

 address = 0xd42490

 address = 0xe919d0
```

Why,After `delete []ptr;` it is still pointing to its previous location(See the 2nd output).

Comment: "as it should"? Who ever said `delete []ptr;` should do anything to the address value in `ptr` itself?

Comment: Why do you believe the result should be something different?

Comment: delete doesn't change value of pointer but deallocate it and you can't change value of pointed memory after that.

Comment: better read docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/delete-operator-cpp?view=vs-2019#:~:text=When%20delete%20is%20used%20to,after%20the%20object%20is%20deleted.

Comment: Looks normal to me. When you call `delete[]` -- that memory you had a valid right to access is simply released for re-use by your program. Nothing happens to the address held by the pointer. It doesn't disappear and it's not marked bad -- it's just a memory location. You can still check the address -- but you can no longer access what is there. When you call `new` again, a new valid region of memory is reserved for your use and your pointer is updated to reflect the starting address for that region -- all normal.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delete[]` is working just as it should. It ensures that destructors are called for the members of the array and marks the memory (internally) as available for re-use.

There's *nothing* in the C++ standard that says it has to zero the memory or return the memory to the OS or clear the variable holding the address you passed to it, etc.

Once you `delete` something, you know destructors have run and you also know that you are *no longer allowed to look at (access) that memory*. If you do anyway, there's no guarantee what you'll get (except [UB](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)).

A pointer is just like a cardboard sign saying "there's something over there". When you use `delete` on the pointer it destroys what's "over there", but it doesn't re-write the sign itself (the pointer), so the pointer still points to the same memory location it always did, but accessing that memory location is now forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

`delete []` has destroyed the array created dynamically at address `ptr`, but has not deleted the pointer itself.

A `ptr = nullptr;` command would perform that job, by indicating that `ptr` now points to nothing.